# GUI.ModalWindow not modal with buttons

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to use a GUI.ModalWindow to stop the user interacting with other items in my scene, but it's still possible to use buttons outside of the ModalWindow.

```
public class ModalDialog : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Rect windowRect = new Rect(100, 130, 220, 100);

    void OnGUI()
    {
        windowRect = GUI.ModalWindow(0, windowRect, DoMyWindow, "My Window");
    }

    void DoMyWindow(int windowID)
    {
        if (GUI.Button(new Rect(10, 20, 100, 20), "Hello World"))
        {
            print("Got a click");
        }
    }
}
```

With the above class (taken from [the Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUI.Window.html)) attached to *Canvas* I am able to click both buttons on the screen:

[image: Screen shot showing setup and error]

Is there something I've missed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer my own question, I contacted Unity support and received the following reply:

> UI components which you create manually, buttons, text etc behave separately from GUI you create trough script because these are 2 separate classes. So the behavior You get is expected and not a bug.

To me this makes the use of ModalWindow somewhat limited as you cannot create your UI using the Unity editor.

To solve my issue I abandoned ModalWindow and instead created a `Canvas` as my root GameObject. I  added a `Panel` GameObject as a child of the canvas and made sure this appeared on top of all my other UI elements. Then when the panel is displayed, the UI elements underneath it cannot be interacted with.

```
Scene
  |- Canvas
      |- Modal Panel
      |- UI Button
```